# Logback - File rolling over on basis of size

Tags: java, spring, jms, logback

We are facing some problems with logback settings in our application (A JMS application configured to receive messages from IBM MQ manager). Its rolling over to new file after every two hours regardless looking at the size settings.
But in case of some other MQ managers like Fiorano, the time is even worse, its rolling over to new file after every few KB's and there is no stoppage on logging by the application means there is no 2hrs lapse.

Below is the logback.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>   
    <appender name="FILEDEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>mylogfile.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

            <fileNamePattern>mylogfile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">              
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>    
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.base22" level="TRACE"/>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILEDEBUG" />
  </root>

  <logger name="org.springframework.transaction.jta">
    <level value="OFF"/> 
  </logger>
</configuration>
```

Question: Is there a way in latest logback releases to configure the time for rollover or to stop it at all to rollover on basis of time? And how to control the behavior in case of fiorano MQ manager.

Answer (score 1):

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <configuration>
    <!--  CONSOLE IF REQUIRED -->
    <!--
      <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" name="CONSOLE">
        <encoder>
          <pattern>[%p] [%thread] %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
      </appender>
    -->  
    <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender" name="FILE"> 
      <File>log/server.log</File>
      <Append>true</Append>
      <BufferedIO>true</BufferedIO>
      <ImmediateFlush>false</ImmediateFlush>
      <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>log/server_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <!-- up to 10 GB max -->
            <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </root>

  <logger name="Main">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
  </logger>     

  <logger name="org.apache">
    <level value="INFO"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="ch.qos">
    <level value="WARN"/>
  </logger>

</configuration>
```

The following versions work together:

- log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar
- logback-classic-1.1.2.jar
- logback-core-1.1.2.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar

After running dummy test (2M of log records) the log folder:

```
 1,947,777 server.log
10,486,143 server_2016-04-28.0.log
10,485,760 server_2016-04-28.1.log
10,485,760 server_2016-04-28.10.log
10,485,760 server_2016-04-28.11.log
10,485,760 server_2016-04-28.2.log
10,485,760 server_2016-04-28.3.log
10,485,760 server_2016-04-28.4.log
10,485,760 server_2016-04-28.5.log
10,486,272 server_2016-04-28.6.log
10,485,760 server_2016-04-28.7.log
10,485,760 server_2016-04-28.8.log
10,485,760 server_2016-04-28.9.log
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i am trying to integrate the updated configurations. Will update you if worked.

Comment: we are using these jars

logback-classic-1.1.3.jar
logback-core-1.1.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar

And it didnt worked. May be its due to the jars combination, but provided the time lines on the project cannot do more tests. May be we are going back to log4j only.

Comment: Thanks for this... but I'm not clear: does this still perform "rollover"/"archive removal" (is this the same thing by the way?) ***only*** on the basis of volume?  Doesn't the line `<fileNamePattern>log/server_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}...` mean that it also rolls over daily as well? Is there a way to do it ONLY on the basis of volume?

Comment: @mike-rodent Try rollingPolicy `FixedWindowRollingPolicy` in conjunction with triggeringPolicy `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy`.